# Display limited content when accordion section is closed

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have used **lightning-accordion** and **lightning-accordion-section** to implement accordion inside a lightning-web-component.

As per th basic functionality of accordion, we don't see any section content when the accordion section is closed.
However, I want to display limited number of character just below the accordion section label even when the section is closed.

Below is how I have implemented the lightning-accordion and would like to know if it's possible to display section content (limited characters) even when the section is closed.

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>My Accordion</h1>
        <lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open={bAllowMultiple}>
          <template for:each={contacts} for:item="contact">
            <lightning-accordion-section key={contact.recId} name={contact.contactName} label={contact.contactName}>
              <div>
                <p>
                  {contact.sComments}
                </p>
              </div>
            </lightning-accordion-section>
          </template>
        </lightning-accordion>
    </div>
</template>
```

sComments would generally have thousands of characters and I want to display say first 100 characters when the section is closed and display full comment when the section is opened. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't think this would be possible with the accordion base component. You would have to construct a custom component. One alternate approach would be to use the `action` slot of the accordion base component to display the gist of the content, but the flip side of this approach is that the gist will display on the right side of the accordion heading and not below it.

Comment: That's gonna be a problem because I want it displayed below accordion heading. makes more sense to construct a custom component. Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to play with `template` and add it after `lightning-accordion-section` and control the visibility of template whenever the event `onsectiontoggle={handleSectionToggle}` on `lightning-accordion` is fired.

First step will be to create an attribute on contacts which takes first 100 hundred characters of `sComments` and store them in the same variable `contacts`. Another attribute to control the visibility for each template under accordian section. So the code may look something like

```
getContactList()
        .then(result => {
            //this.contacts = result;
              result.forEach(contact => {
                  contact.label = contact.sComments.slice(0,100);
                  contact.showPara = true;
              });
              this.contacts = result;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
        });
```

After that make changes to markup as below by adding `onsectiontoggle={handleSectionToggle}` and a template after the accordion-section

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <h1>My Accordion</h1>
    <lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open={bAllowMultiple} onsectiontoggle={handleSectionToggle}>
      <template for:each={contacts} for:item="contact">
        <lightning-accordion-section key={contact.recId} name={contact.contactName} label={contact.contactName}>
          <div>
            <p>
              {contact.sComments}
            </p>
          </div>
        </lightning-accordion-section>
        <template if:true={contact.showPara}>
            <p key={contact.Id}>{contact.label}</p>
        </template>
      </template>
    </lightning-accordion>
</div>
```

Now in the js file the code for method `handleSectionToggle` will be

```
handleSectionToggle(event) {
    const openSections = event.detail.openSections;
    this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-accordion-section').forEach(elem => {
        if(openSections.includes(elem.name)) {
            this.contacts[this.contacts.findIndex(item => item.Name == elem.name)].showPara = false;
        }
        else {
            this.contacts[this.contacts.findIndex(item => item.Name == elem.name)].showPara = true;
        }
    });    
}
```

This way the label of the accordian section will change as you expand and contract them.

Comment: Wouldn't your code sample simply display the first 100 char (of section content) without the actual heading of the accordion section? So, the collapsed sections would display this way while the expanded sections would have precise headings. I guess the question is whether this 100 char (of section content) can be displayed right below the section heading when the section is collapsed

Comment: @maniac coder as mentioned by arut, I actually want to display the first 100 characters right below the section heading when the section is collapsed just to show a gist of the actual content.

Comment: @ashutosh I have updated my answer and added a new <p> under a template whose visibility can be controlled when accordion is clicked.

Comment: @maniaccoder thanks, that actually works.. appreciate it.